# o:graphicImage images not displayed

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

I've been facing an issue with `Omnifaces 2.1`.

I have an images type `byte[]` stored in my database with a declaration  java class like this:

```
 @Lob
    private byte[] image;
```

In my xhtml file I have a loop on a class that has an image in it:

```
<ui:repeat var="listT" value="#{eventBean.listEvents}">                                             
<o:graphicImage value="#{eventBean.getImage(listT.idEvent)}"  dataURI="true" />  
</ui:repeat>
```

Now in my `bean` I tried implementing the `getImage()` function mentioned in the documentation of omnifaces:

```
 @ManagedBean
 @ViewScoped
 public class EventBean implements Serializable {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 @EJB
 private EventServiceLocal eventServiceLocal;
 private Event event = new Event();
 private List<Event> listEvents;
 private List<Event> listEventsval;
 private static Event eventSt;
 private UploadedFile file;

 public byte[] getImage(int eventID) {

    return eventServiceLocal.listEventspicture(eventID);
}
```

When I execute this I gt no image and when I inspect the element, I get this as a result:

```
 <o:graphicimage value="[B@1aeef88" datauri="true"></o:graphicimage>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> when i execute this i got no image and when inspect the element i get this as result :
>
> ```
> <o:graphicimage value="[B@1aeef88" datauri="true"></o:graphicimage>
> ```

In other words, `<o:xxx>` tags don't work at all. This is not restricted to `<o:graphicImage>` alone. All other `<o:xxx>` tags in the same page would also not work.

That can have 2 causes:

1. OmniFaces is not installed in webapp.
2. The `o` XML namespace is not declared in the XHTML page.

The normal procedure to solve this is:

1. Add OmniFaces JAR file to `/WEB-INF/lib` (or let your dependency manager do it).
2. Add `xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui` to some parent element.

To verify the working:

1. When exporting a WAR file from your project and inspecting it using a ZIP tool, the physical OmniFaces JAR file should be present in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder and there should be a line like below in server log during deployment:

   > INFO [org.omnifaces.ApplicationInitializer] Using OmniFaces version 2.6.8
2. There should be no `<o:xxx>` tags anywhere in the generated HTML output.